# Минимальное и максимальное значения числа типа signed double

Tags: c, c++

Собственно, хотелось бы узнать минимальное и максимальное значения числа типа signed double. Если исходить из этого, [число двойной точности](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), то нужно сдвинуть границы на (максимум/2)?

Comment: signed относится только к целым типам, double всегда идет со знаком

Comment: положительное число в любой степени>=0;
положительное * положительное>0;

   Minimum value for double: 2.22507e-308;
   Maximum value for double: 1.79769e+308;

объясните, где тут отрицательные числа?

Comment: -Infinity, +Infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрицательные будут такими же, только с минусом. 2.22507e-308 самое маленькое **положительное** -2.22507e-308 самое большое (самое близкое к нулю) **отрицательное**.

Для 1.79769e+308 и -1.79769e+308 аналогично (в смысле самые удаленные от нуля).

[@Магомед](/users/7602/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4), дело в том, что машинный формат целых и с плавающей точкой отличаются не только наличием экспоненты, но и представлением мантиссы. (И наличием знака у чисел с плавающей точкой).

Подробнее посмотрите в сети, что-нибудь вроде: **формат чисел с плавающей точкой".

Answer (score 3):

В с++ есть такой чудесный файл - [limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/). Подставляете нужный тип и получаете ответы. Вот ответ [ideone](http://ideone.com/p3H5F) для double.